# Setup devise to only have one master user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have setup devise on a site and now the client just wants to be able to use 1 master password and not allow anyone else to create accounts. I removed the create account links from the login page and I also extended my RegistrationsController to look like this.

```
class CustomRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController


    # used to override normal create behavior
    def create
            redirect_to user_session_path
    end

    # used to override normal new behavior. Redirects user back to the login page
    def new
            redirect_to user_session_path
    end
end
```

Then in my routes file I have

```
devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}, :controllers => { :registrations => "custom_registrations"}
```

Now I'm trying to find a way where I can either hardcode a master username and password or come up with a better approach to this.

Comment: Using Devise feels like overkill for a single-user application. Unless you expect the client to change their mind and decide they want multiple users again sometime soon, maybe you should take it out and roll your own simple login?

Comment: I agree but I want to use it because they will most lightly go back to a user setup in the coming months. But for now I just need a way to only allow one account.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means an elegant solution, but you could simply use a migration (or the database seed file, if the database is still new enough to be generated that way) to create a single User object with the desired login info, and add a validation on User that returns false if there's already an existing User.